# Alternative for instanceOf (State Pattern)

Tags: java, design-patterns, instanceof, state-pattern

I'm having a problem using the state pattern, I don't know how to check if a `State` is of a certain instance without using `instanceOf` (because that is considered a bad practice).

`TCPConnection` holds a `TCPState` object.
Let's say I want to get all the `TCPConnections` that have the state `TCPEstablished`. How would I do this?
[image]

A way would be:

```
public List<TCPConnection> getAllEstablished() {
  List<TCPConnection> list = new ArrayList<TCPConnection>();

  for(TCPConnection tcp : allConnections) {
      if(tcp.getState().instanceOf(TCPEstablished)) {
          list.add(tcp);
      }
  }

  return list;
}
```

But this uses `instanceOf` and I would prefer not to use that. Are there any better ways? Or is my use of `instanceOf` valid?

Comment: For state management, I would use `enum` rather than classes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using `instanceof` operator in your case. However, the usage is syntactically incorrect. `instanceof` is not a method, it's an operator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why would an enum be better?

Comment: Why is instanceOf not good practice?

Comment: @JClassic: It isn't bad practice it is a code smell. If you need to know what class a variable is you probably have too tight of coupling and need to rethink how you are using that variable. That isn't always the case (serializing being an obvious example) but it is something to keep in mind when using the operator.

Comment: @Guvante what if I have something that returns a random `GameState` out of the set of `[Game, Setting, Menu]`, but I want to do an operation based on what State i receive? Since they all extend State, and are received as such?

Comment: btw, `tcp.getState().instanceOf(TCPEstablished)` breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: @JClassic: Usually you make it a method of the `GameState` but it really depends on the specifics. I usually try to avoid using `instanceof` to make semantic changes as that makes the coupling very very tight. For instance if I added a `SubMenu` that inherits from `Menu` I end up with a lot of unknown behavior that is embedded in various places that call `instanceof` without my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the use of `instanceOf` is considered a smell. Furhermore, checking for the type of a state object goes contrary to the idea of the state pattern itself (encapsulate state-dependant behavior in the subtypes such that such checks become unnecessary).

Nevertheless you could technically get rid of the `instanceOf` by adding another operation to `TCPState`, e.g. `bool isEstablished()`, and implement it such that it returns `true` only on `TCPEstablished`.

```
interface TCPState {
    ...
    boolean isEstablished();
}

class TCPEstablished implements TCPState {
    ...
    boolean isEstablished() {
        return true;
    }
}

class TCPClosed implements TCPState {
    ...
    boolean isEstablished() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add the operation to `TCPConnection`:

```
class TCPConnection {
    ...
    boolean isEstablished() {
        return this.getState().isEstablished();
    }
}
```

Then your operation `getAllEstablished` would look like this:

```
List<TCPConnection> getAllEstablished() {
    List<TCPConnection> list = new ArrayList<TCPConnection>();

    for(TCPConnection tcp : allConnections) {
        if(tcp.isEstablished()) {
            list.add(tcp);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

`instanceOf` is gone. But is it worth it?

Answer (score 3):

You can make your states an enum

```
public enum TCPState{
  ESTABLISHED,
  LISTEN,
  CLOSED;

  ..methods go here

}
```

Since enum values are full fledged objects they can override methods to do state specific behavior.  You can then do `equals()` or even `==` checks to check state.

```
for(TCPConnection tcp : allConnections) {
  if(tcp.getState()==TCPState.Established)) {
      list.add(tcp);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's how to make each enum value have a different implementation for a method.

let's say `TCPState` implements an interface or has an abstract method `foo()`

```
public enum TCPState{
  ESTABLISHED,
  LISTEN,
  CLOSED;

 public abstract void foo();

}
```

You can then implement the method differently for each value like this:

```
 public enum TCPState{
  ESTABLISHED{
     @Override
     public void foo(){
         System.out.println("established");
     }
  },
  LISTEN{
     @Override
     public void foo(){
         System.out.println("listening");
     }
  },
  CLOSED{
     @Override
     public void foo(){
         System.out.println("closed");
     }
  }
  ;

 public abstract void foo();

}
```

Alternatively, you can make a base implementation in TCPSTate instead of declaring it `abstract` and then only use overrides in the values that need to do something different.

Comment: Also, the `State` doesn't need to know how to open or close a connection.

Comment: How would you make sure all three methods all have three different implementations per state?